# CSS Flexbox divs auto change order to fill empty space

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I have a grid layout with identical fixed height and fixed width divs, and I need to insert a bigger div in between the lines of this grid without breaking the flow, with a random HTML position.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="big"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
```

And the layout I want, with the HTML order of the divs:

[image]

The main problem is the responsive behaviour, because I don't know how many elements will be in a row.
My first idea was to use JS to place the big div, but it was not reliable, and not clean.

I can change the flex order of the divs with JS, but a full-css code would be definitely better.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. One example: *...without breaking the flow, with a random HTML position..* If you could provide more detail, and maybe a specific question, that would help.

Comment: If you don't know in advance which index the `big` div will have within its parent you need a script to solve this.

Comment: What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: If I am right here the OP wants the n:th div (which can be randomly choosen) to have full width and as such stay on a row of its own while the rest items take its place until the parents width is full and then continues in a row below the n:th div. As I see it, it can be solved with the `order` property, though the n:th div's index is needed along with the amount of div's.

Comment: I suggest you go through the [flex properties](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) again and examine the purposes of `flex-basis`, `flex-grow` and how content behaves when you justify content with `space-between` or `space-around`.

Comment: does the container around the flexboxes and the boxes themselves have a fixed width?

Comment: @LGSon This is exactly what I want, thanks for explaining it better.

Comment: @Edrees The container width is 100vw, and the boxes have a fixed width (in px)

Comment: not sure this might also be useful to understand flexbox better. http://flexboxfroggy.com/ + i created this very quickly in codepen you can have a look at it as well: http://codepen.io/Edrees21/pen/RrVVJR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some thinking I came up with this, without script.

It uses media queries and you need to do some calculating of your own, to set all the width's according to your requirements.

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3bj8ooy/3/), which has 2 groups, each with a different `big`, having the same CSS, showing a way that might work for you, and below a code snippet, with only 1 group though.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 400px;
}
.parent div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  order: 1;
}
.parent div:before {
  content: attr(data-nr);
}
.parent .small {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
}
.parent .big {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 400px;
  order: 2;
}
.parent .big ~ .small {
  border-color: red;
  order: 3;
}
.parent .big ~ div:nth-of-type(n+0) {
  order: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .parent .big ~ .small:nth-of-type(n+10) {
    order: 3;
  }  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .parent .big ~ .small:nth-of-type(n+9) {
    order: 3;
  }  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .parent .big ~ .small:nth-of-type(n+8) {
    order: 3;
  }  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .parent .big ~ .small:nth-of-type(n+7) {
    order: 3;
  }  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .parent .big ~ .small:nth-of-type(n+6) {
    order: 3;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="small" data-nr="1"></div>
  <div class="small" data-nr="2"></div>
  <div class="small" data-nr="3"></div>
  <div class="big" data-nr="4"></div>
  <div class="small" data-nr="5"></div>
  <div class="small" data-nr="6"></div>
  <div class="small" data-nr="7"></div>
  <div class="small" data-nr="8"></div>
  <div class="small" data-nr="9"></div>
  <div class="small" data-nr="10"></div>
</div>
```